# Как узнать id последнего поста в телеграмм канале python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Нужно сделать уведомление ботом (пересылать сообщение из канала пользователю), когда появляется новый пост из определенной категории. Пришел к выводу, что требуется получать id выпущенного только что поста, чтобы бот мог методом forward_message (или подобным) или же просто ссылкой отправить пост юзеру. Есть вариант с getUpdates, но проблема в том, что когда бот запущен, то сообщения доходят моментально и getUpdates их не получает. Также, метод getUpdates получает инфу не только с канала, но и от пользователей, поэтому вылавливать инфу с канала будет проблематично. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Добавил бота в админы канала и использую декоратор @bot.channel_post_handler(). В этом случае получить id вышедшего поста не проблема.